# How would i send a payload with my post request in c#?

Tags: c#, authentication, post, request, payload

I am trying to login to a website and i need to send the credentials as a payload but I don't understand how payloads are sent.

```cs
public class LoginClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public LoginClient()
    {
        _client = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task Put()
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"https://accounts.nike.com/challenge/password/v1"))
        {
            using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to send? text or json?

Comment: The request has a Content Property that needs to be set. How can be found in the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.content?view=net-6.0

Comment: @KrishnaVarma i am trying to send json

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send Json, use `PostAsync` to set the content

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var url = $"https://accounts.nike.com/challenge/password/v1";
var data = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");    

var response = await client.PostAsync(url, data);
```